# Django -Help displaying content in nested for loop

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a Requisition which may have multiple lines. So to implement this I included a unique_together constraint on two fields on the RequisitionLine model which one of the fields is a FK to Requisition . So naturally to pull all the lines of a requisition I would query the RequisitionLine table where the FK = the id of the Requisition model, then iterate over all the sequences to grab all the lines.

My goal is to display the header number with the lines of that requisition under the header in the template but am struggling to accomplish this. I have tried to iterate over the queryset but the code i am posting below is my most recent attempt trying pass lists to the template which is also not working. Right now each header is showing all the lines. Any help would be appreciated.

### Models.py

```
class Requisition(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='req_user')

    signature = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)



class RequisitionLine(models.Model):

    parent_req = models.ForeignKey('Requisition', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='par_req_line' )
    sequence = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    item_code = models.ForeignKey(
        'items.ItemMaster', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='req_item', blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    extra_information = models.TextField(blank=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0,null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0.00,null=True)
    purchase_order = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True,null=True)
    po_line = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    req_delivery_date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    act_delivar_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey('RequisitionStatus', related_name='req_status', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    assistance = models.ForeignKey('users.UserRoles', related_name='req_assist', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to= ~Q(role='Requestor'))
    catagory = models.ForeignKey('items.ItemCatagory', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='line_cat',  blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('parent_req','sequence')
```

### Views.py

```
def pending_action(request):
user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=request.user)
user_req_headers = Requisition.objects.filter(username=user)
complete_status = RequisitionStatus.objects.get(status='Completed')
req_line_list = []

for req_header in user_req_headers:
    req_lines = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(Q(parent_req = req_header) & ~Q(status=complete_status))
    req_line_list.append(req_lines)

return render(request, 'req/pending_action.html', {'user_req_headers':user_req_headers,'req_line_list':req_line_list})
```

### pending_action.html

```
{% for header in user_req_headers %}    
    <h3>{{header}}</h3>
    {% for req_line in req_line_list %}
    {% for req in req_line %}    
    <table>
        {% if forloop.first  %}
        <tr>
            <th>description</th>
            <th>catagory</th>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}
        <tr>
            <!-- FOR LOOP HERE TO ITERATE OF LIST OF QUERYSETS-->

            <td>{{ req }}</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Django actually has a build in solution for this. It's a template tag called regroup, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup . the docs even include a pretty useful and easy to follow along example as well. If you have any problems implementing it just ping me here.

Comment: @DisneylandSC Im sorry I am having a heard time implementing this. In the example a dictionary is being used so the attribute is obvious. How can i relate that user to a list of lists? i also have 2 lists as well.

Comment: You apply the regroup tag to a queryset. Basically what it does is exactly what you are trying to achieve with your sets. So I would simply not use this set tactic and just query the records I want displayed and then use regroup on this queryset to display the header(s) that I want it to display. If you want more than one level of indention with headers you can simply nest the regroup tags.

Comment: @DisneylandSC I updated my Views.py. I have a list of querysets now. Is it possible to apply the regroup tag to a list of query sets? If so how?

Comment: The regroup tag is applied to querysets. You have a list of query sets. Just put the regroup logic inside the template for loop of the list.

Comment: @DisneylandSC That doesnt really solve my problem because my ultimate goal was to display the header and once the user clicked on the header it would display the lines pertaining to that header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a queryset of the header and using a reverse relationship to capture the lines associated with each header

```
<table class="table">
        {% for req_header in req_header_list %}
            <tr>

                <ul>{{ req_header }}
                {% for line in req_header.par_req_line.all %}
                    <li>{{line}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </tr>

        {% endfor %}

    </table>
```